# With a dart class that has a parameter of type list, how is it possible to make it equatable

Tags: testing, flutter, dart, bloc, equatable

I'm playing around with the new library bloc_test for flutter and I implemented the following test

```
blocTest('should return ReservationsLoadSucess when the use case returns a list of reservationsList',

    build: () {
      when(mockGetReservations(any)).thenAnswer((_) async => Right(reservationsList));
      return ReservationBloc(getReservations: mockGetReservations);
    },
    act: (bloc) async {
      bloc.add(ReservationsRequested(user));
    },
    expect: [
      ReservationsInitial(),
      ReservationsLoadInProgress(),
      ReservationsLoadSuccess(reservationsList),
    ],
  );
```

This is the implementation of ReservationsLoadSuccess

```
class ReservationsLoadSuccess extends ReservationState {
  final List<Reservation> list;

  ReservationsLoadSuccess(this.list);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [list];
}
```

Where ReservationState extends Equatable
Now, when running the test, you get the following error

```
should return ReservationsLoadSucess when the use case returns a list of reservationsList:

ERROR: Expected: [
            ReservationsInitial:ReservationsInitial,
            ReservationsLoadInProgress:ReservationsLoadInProgress,
            ReservationsLoadSuccess:ReservationsLoadSuccess
          ]
  Actual: [
            ReservationsInitial:ReservationsInitial,
            ReservationsLoadInProgress:ReservationsLoadInProgress,
            ReservationsLoadSuccess:ReservationsLoadSuccess
          ]
   Which: was ReservationsLoadSuccess:<ReservationsLoadSuccess> instead of ReservationsLoadSuccess:<ReservationsLoadSuccess> at location [2]
```

Basically saying that the state ReservationsLoadSuccess at position 2 in the actual list is not equal to its peer in the expected list.

I tried overriding the == operator in the ReservationsLoadSuccess class as follows

```
class ReservationsLoadSuccess extends ReservationState {
  final List<Reservation> list;

  ReservationsLoadSuccess(this.list);

  final Function eq = const ListEquality().equals;
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is ReservationsLoadSuccess &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          eq(list, other.list);
}
```

But that didn't seem to work and running the test still outputted the same error. The only way I got it to work is to leave the props method returning an empty list or adding any other dummy variable and pass it to the props list.

Is there any way I can make the class equatable in regards to the list parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking into the package [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable). It is used often when applying BLoC pattern.

Comment: I did mention that ReservationState abstract class does extend equatable. But the implementation of Equatable does not cover the scenario where you have an iterable as a variable. What equatable does is basically loop on all of the parameters of your class and compares them to theit peers in the other instance. Now, when you compare a list to another one with the same elements, it does not return true unless it is actually the same list (referential equality)